# How to prevent my app from making a new instance

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, instance

If i open my app a second time, it has to open the same instance as was opened before.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You probably need to read about the Windows Phone Application Execution Model : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way your app will open the same instance is if the user leaves with the start button, then comes back using the back stack.  In order to preserve the experience in this instance, you need to use Tombstoning.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148153.aspx

If you need them to be able to come back to the same experience, in every instance of starting the app, then you need to save the data each time it is changed, and when the app starts, you need to refresh the display with that saved data.  You can do this using the ApplicationSettings of IsolatedStorage. http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings

Here are a couple of other resources to look at:

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your respone. However, i know that my program goes into dormant state. But i have a open stream (tcp) with my server for receiving messages. If i go to the background i use pushnotifications. So if i click on the app icon, i want to do to the same page as it was left (when going to the background).

Comment: You could use deep linking, which could implement either a secondary tile, or the toast notification, eihter (or both) of which could deep-link to another page. There is no way to use the primary tile to go to a location other than the MainPage of the app, as a new instance.